# A string Variable in SSIS is not populating with the value generated in a C# script

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a fairly simple requirement to read the filename from a location and populate a variable with the filename. I am using a script task for this task. No matter what I try, the value of the filename is not populating in the variable.

I'm using a Script task Editor. There is only one ReadWriteVariables which will hold the full name of the file.

**Here is the script that I'm using:**

```
namespace ST_f8fd828f11b64932b15f2681e86c8d94
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
         public void Main()
        {

            string p = "C:\\Users\\nthaku01\\Desktop\\NewEXPOLD.txt";

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(p);
            String fileName = fi.FullName;
            Dts.Variables["User::vLastFilename"].Value = fileName.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::vLastFilename"].Value.ToString());

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

The MessageBox displays the name(and path) of the file. However, the variable is empty.

This issue has been discussed in detail previously as well and I tried every trick. However, it is just not working for me. Please help!!

Thanks,

Navneet

Comment: You say your variable is empty, but you don't say how you're checking the value. I used the code from your script task, and the variable value assignment works fine. However, I did come across a few issues with your `enum` section.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your script task that I could see is that `ScriptResults` was already defined for the script. I renamed your `enum` section and the enumerators, and I have no problem using the variable to insert the text into a db table. Here's the script task I used:

```
public void Main()
    {

        string p = "C:\\Users\\nthaku01\\Desktop\\NewEXPOLD.txt";

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(p);
        String fileName = fi.FullName;
        Dts.Variables["User::vLastFilename"].Value = fileName.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::vLastFilename"].Value.ToString());

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)eScriptResults.enumSuccess;
    }

    enum eScriptResults
    {
        enumSuccess = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        enumFailure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved.

Actually, as an SSIS newbie, I was not aware that the value is assigned to the variable during the run-time does not show up in the variable window.

In the variable window, only the value mentioned at the design time shows up. I had to create a derived column and I assigned the value of the user variable to this newly created derived column. This resolved the issue I was facing.

In the Derived column transformation:

**output_LastFileName** <-- User::vLastFilename